# Оператор Case SQlServer

Tags: sql-server, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот скрипт, я нахожу наиболее часто продаваемый инструмент, т.е инструмент, который часто встречается во всех накладных

```
SELECT top 1 Instrumenty.Nazvanie_instrumenta As наиболее_продаваемые_инструменты_за_февраль,
Sum(kolichestvo_prod) as количество                 
FROM         dbo.Instrumenty INNER JOIN 
dbo.Prodaja_tovarov ON dbo.Instrumenty.Id_instrumenta = dbo.Prodaja_tovarov.Id_instrumenta inner join
dbo.Nakladnaya_rashoda ON dbo.Prodaja_tovarov.Id_nakladnoiProd = dbo.Nakladnaya_rashoda.Id_nakladnoiProd
Where Data between '2011-02-01' and '2011-02-28' 
Group by Instrumenty.Nazvanie_instrumenta
Having COUNT(Prodaja_tovarov.Id_nakladnoiProd)>1       
Order by SUM(kolichestvo_prod) desc
```

Вот, как этот же запрос написать через оператор Case?

Comment: А если перед всем этим поставить 4 пробела - Вы (и не только) приятно удивитесь... :DDDD (лучше будет применить к коду).

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, а куда нужен оператор CASE то? Единственное что пришло на ум - убрать having . Тогда так:

```
SELECT 
    Instrumenty.Nazvanie_instrumenta As наиболее_продаваемые_инструменты_за_февраль,
    Sum
    (
        CASE
            WHEN
                EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT NULL
                        FROM Prodaja_tovarov.Id_instrumenta
                        inner join dbo.Nakladnaya_rashoda ON dbo.Prodaja_tovarov.Id_nakladnoiProd = dbo.Nakladnaya_rashoda.Id_nakladnoiProd
                        WHERE
                            dbo.Instrumenty.Id_instrumenta = dbo.Prodaja_tovarov.Id_instrumenta
                    )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) as количество                 
FROM dbo.Instrumenty
Where Data between '2011-02-01' and '2011-02-28' 
Group by Instrumenty.Nazvanie_instrumenta
```

Comment: оооу, спасибо большое!!!